# Data base tables get deleted on heroku in django app

Tags: python, django, database, heroku

Data base tables get deleted on heroku, even i am using cloudinary storage for static-files. I am using default database sqlite3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i found out that heroku cleans the database tables of sqlite3. The solution is to use a different database, like postgreSQL.